# Self invoking anonymouse functions with document parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the difference between:

```
(function(document) {
    //do stuff with document
})(document);
```

and

```
(function() {
    //do stuff with document
})();
```

I'm unsure why the convention appears to be to pass `document` and sometimes `window` too to the function? Is it to do with scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons for this:

**1. Using less global variables**
By injecting the function with the global variable it will depend on only the argument and not a global variable which might be used multiple times.

**2. Creating a local scope**
An IIFE is a way to create a new scope by declaring a function and immediately invoking it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) for more information.

**3. Better minify**

For example if you will minify your example it will change from this:

```
(function(document) {
    //do stuff with document
})(document);
```

To this:

```
(function(a) {
    //do stuff with a
})(document);
```

Notice the `a`, which is shorter than your `document`.

*Edit: Fixed typos*

Comment: Useful link. Found this which answers this for me: "Performance benefit of using IIFE’s is the ability to pass commonly used global objects like window, document etc as an argument by reduce the scope lookup.(Remember Javascript looks for property in local scope and way up chaining till global scope). So accessing global objects at local scope reduce the lookup time like below."

Answer (score 6):

This becomes especially handy if you use a compressor/uglifier like UglifyJS. It then replaces `document` with say `a`, making your code shorter.

So something like

```
(function(document, window){
  var body = document.body;
  var foo = document.querySelector('foo');
  var bar = document.querySelector('bar');
})(document, window);
```

becomes

```
(function(a, b){
  var c = a.body;
  var d = a.querySelector('foo');
  var e = a.querySelector('bar');
})(document, window);
```

If you did not place document and window in the function it'll just keep saying document;

```
(function(){
  var c = document.body;
  var d = document.querySelector('foo');
  var e = document.querySelector('bar');
})();
```

Comment: but if you don't put any document then isn't is shorter ?

Comment: () is shorter than (a).

Comment: @victor175 yeah that's what i asked him too

Comment: Yeah but if you use `document` many times in your JS file it will eventually be way shorter

Comment: lol, so short example doesn't illustrate your point. Indeed, the same many times will safe characters

Comment: Haha yeah with just one line of code it doesn't really matter, edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

An immediately invoking function expression (IIFE) creates a new local scope. Just like any function, you can pass in arguments when you call it. `document` and `window` are globals in JavaScript web api, and are made available when you run js in the browser. By passing them into an IIFE, you can access them as whatever you want inside due to scope. For example:

```
(function(w, d) {
  console.log(w); // window
  console.log(d); // document
})(window, document);

console.log(w); // Uncaught ReferenceError: w is not defined
console.log(a); // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

The reason `w` and `a` are not defined in the second set of `console.log`s is because they are locally scoped to the IIFE.

Comment: And why do I want them in the local scope?

Comment: Scope is an extremely important programming paradigm. It prevents naming clashes and unexpected behaviour.